# Is it faster to have Rails or Postges do sorting?

Tags: postgresql, performance, ruby-on-rails-5, sql-order-by

I have a Rails 5 application with a Postgres 10 database.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a performance difference between doing this

```
MyModel.order(:created_at).last
```

vs

```
MyModel.order(:created_at => :desc).first
```

I have no index on the "created_at," column -- it is the same as was auto-generated when I first created my table from a Rails migration.

Comment: If you need to sort 100 million rows, I'm sure Postgres will be faster. If you need to sort only 100 rows, I don't think there will a big difference

Comment: Is there any difference between sorting in ascending order and grabbing the last record vs sorting in descending order and grabbing the first record?

Comment: That would depend on how you grab the last one. Could you get it directly without spinning through the first ones. Again as @a_horse_with_no_name indicates that would depend on volume.  However a better approach would be let SQL do all the work. Eliminate as many rows in the WHERE clause as possible, sort descending, limit 1. And just return the desired single row. In general do as much of the work as possible in sql.

Comment: @Belayer, you say "that would depend on how you grab the last one," but I was under the impression that the Rails "MyModel.order(:created_at).last" construct does the grabbing for me and that I don't have control over that.

Comment: I have no idea, I do not use Rails. I would change the query to just return a single row (unless there other uses for the remainder of the data).  Looking as your statement appears Rails is doing the sorting (but it could be generating an order by). As the data volume grows that will get slower, both in time for Rails to sort, and in time to transmit the data from the database server to it.

Answer (score 1):

Two command asks same amount of work to PostgreSQL
It is obvious when you look at SQL of both command

```
MyModel.order(:created_at).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"my_model\".* FROM \"my_model\" ORDER BY \"my_model\".\"created_at\" ASC"
```

vs

```
MyModel.order(created_at: :desc).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"my_model\".* FROM \"my_model\" ORDER BY \"my_model\".\"created_at\" DESC"
```

Both command asks PostgreSQL to order all rows with created_at column value.
So there is no difference between two command